# LDAP Search: find uid and cn mismatch

Tags: ldap

We have an application that uses LDAP, and (for reasons known to the developers) requires the CN field to be the same as the UID field.  I would like to search for entries where that is not the case, but I have not been able to find advice on constructing a search.

Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: You won't be able to do it with a command-line search. Get the developers to do it for you. It's their problem, let them help to solve it. But I would be interested to know why they have come up with such a constraint. It shouldn't be necessary, and in fact it's a violation of 3rd-normal form.